# AngularJS: load more data after main page loads

Tags: angularjs, web-worker

I'm making an app in Angular (v1.6.10) where I'd like the main elements on the page to load first, allowing the user to interact with the page, and then use a service to load additional supplementary data (~50-100 network requests) / refresh certain elements on the page (e.g. load the text, then load the highlights and annotations that would style the text).

What is the right way / potential options to do this in Angular (render some stuff, get some data, then refresh elements)? I've looked into:

- WebWorkers - seems like the use case is more for heavy-duty background processing, and getting access to the service in the webworker looks tricky
- `setTimeout` to intersperse the requests with other work - I'm not sure if this is the best way

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AngularJS (version < 2) and Angular (version >= 2) are two different frameworks. Please be mindful of that when tagging questions. Also, your question is quite broad and phrased in a way that invites opinions rather than objective answers. You may want to read [ask] for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

One can chain requests:

```
$http.get(API+"/initialData")
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.initialData = response.data;
    return $http.get(API+"/moreData");
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.moreData = response.data;
});
```

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain.

The AngularJS framework will render the data as it arrives from the server.